# Mongodb Aggregate: Calculate number of persons between two country which are Max-Payments and Min-Payments

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, average, divide

[db format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPOo0.png)

DB people FORMAT

```
>  {
>     _id: ObjectId("576865c1bab6cf2f2fb39d8f"),
>     firstName: 'Zofia',
>     lastName: 'Wojciechowska',
>     sex: 'female',
>     address: {
>       country: 'Poland',
>       city: 'Warsaw',
>       postalCode: '05-075',
>       street: 'Wilcza'
>     },
>     birthDate: ISODate("1974-11-18T12:11:00.000Z"),
>     payments: [
>       { category: 'relax', name: 'holidays', amount: 282.46 },
>       { category: 'food', name: 'store', amount: 15.18 },
>       { category: 'food', name: 'store', amount: 64.09 },
>       { category: 'food', name: 'restaurant', amount: 26.32 },
>       { category: 'health', name: 'pharmacy', amount: 53.27 },
>       { category: 'food', name: 'restaurant', amount: 43.56 },
>       { category: 'health', name: 'doctor', amount: 142.27 },
>       { category: 'relax', name: 'holidays', amount: 959.59 },
>       { category: 'health', name: 'pharmacy', amount: 61.14 },
>       { category: 'health', name: 'doctor', amount: 102.29 }
>     ],
>     wealth: {
>       bankAccounts: [ { bank: 'Pekao SA', balance: 18643.26 } ],
>       realEstates: [
>         { type: 'flat', worth: 599000 },
>         { type: 'flat', worth: 684000 }
>       ],
>       market: { stocks: [], bonds: [] },
>       credits: [
>         {
>           bank: 'Bank Zachodni WBK',
>           type: 'mortgage',
>           value: 499985.3
>         }
```

I need to calculate the fraction between NUMBERS of persons between two countries (Max and Min payments amount).

- Max country is maximum payments.amount for 'restaurant' (payments.name) and Min country is minimum payments.amount for 'restaurant')

Anyone have an idea about this issue?
Please help me and thank you about this

My code is at below that I just finished, but I am stucking at advanced request: "Now calculate the same fraction, but Number Persons of Max country just ONLY count on [NUMBER OF PERSONs have payments higher than AVG of MIN country]

```
db.people.aggregate([ 
    { $unwind: "$payments" }, 
    { $match: { "payments.name": "restaurant" } }, 
    { $group: { 
        _id: { country: "$address.country" }, 
        avgPayment: { $avg: "$payments.amount" },
        noPerson: { $sum: 1}
        } }, 
    { $sort : {"avgPayment": -1}},
    { $group: {
        _id: { country: "$address.country" },
        max:  {$first: "$$ROOT"},
        min: { $last: "$$ROOT"}
    }},
    { $project: {res: {$divide: [ "$max.noPerson","$min.noPerson"
    ]},
    _id: 0}}
])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please add the db format as a text in code format, and explain what did you try and what is your expected result

Comment: Please add your current code to get data.
based on that people on StackOverflow can help you to modify your query.

Comment: After getting the max amount and no of persons and minimum amount and number of person what you're trying to achieve? Can you please more clarify it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.